# Discord V13 VoiceStateUpdate doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I m rewriting my bot for latest version.

I dont understand why this isn't working.

```
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    let userchID = newMember.channelID;
    let oldUserChannel = oldMember.channelID;
    let chat = bot.channels.cache.get(settings.channel.chatstreamer);

    if (userchID === settings.channel.stream){
        chat.permissionOverwrite.edit(newMember.id, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: true,
            VIEW_CHANNEL: true
        });
        return true;
    } else if (oldUserChannel === settings.channel.stream) {
        chat.permissionOverwrites.get(oldMember.id).delete();
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Discord V13 your `newMember.channelID` and `oldMember.channelID` needs to be changed to `newMember.channelId` and `oldMember.channelId`.

Just need to make the D lowercase.